# MediaContextNotificatioNWindow Error Occurs When Trying to Shutdown Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown

I am working with a Windows XP laptop that whenever it is shutdown will display a warning that the "MediaContextNotificationWindow" is attempting to close, eventually requiring you to force it to close.  It does not appear to matter if the laptop is on or off the network, it will still display the message.  I have done a little research into the MediaContextNotificationWindow, and it seems like it is either a part of the Windows Media Player or .Net 3.5, though I'm not entirely sure.

Has anyone come across this error and know how to resolve it?